# Powershell Script to remote enable MS defender on multiple computers

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft365-defender

I'm looking for some advice on enabling defending remotely on multiple devices.. I have done a bunch of googling but I would like a another set of eyes on what I have done so far before I take this to test. This is my first major script that will be going into prod when completed.

```
$credential = (Get-Credential)
$csv        = import-csv "c:\temp\computers.csv"
foreach($computer in $csv)
    Invoke-command –computername $Computer.name -ScriptBlock .\.vscode
{
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false
Set-MpPreference -DisableIOAVProtection $false
#Set-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "Path to folder"
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name "Real-Time Protection" -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection" -Name "DisableBehaviorMonitoring" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection" -Name "DisableOnAccessProtection" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection" -Name "DisableScanOnRealtimeEnable" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name "DisableAntiSpyware" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
start-service WinDefend
start-service WdNisSvc
}
```